# Polar equation area in relation to a square

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I'm having trouble with a question. I don't know where to start, but have made an attempt.

> A curve has polar equation $r^2=a^2\sin2\theta$. What is the area of the smallest possible square which encloses the whole curve?

I tried with simple values such as a = 1, and tried to find the "width" of the curve to no avail (the maximum x point in a Cartesian sense).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The axis of symmetry is $y=x$ and the min area is for a square which has sides parallel to coordinate axes. Find the slope and when the tangents are parallel to x-axis. That should give you the length of the side of the square.

Comment: You could write the formula of distance of tangent line from the origin in polar coords, then find its maximum $d$. Square side is not less than $2d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trying things out, I finally got the answer.

$$y=r\sin\theta=a\sqrt{\sin2\theta}\sin\theta
\\\frac{dy}{d\theta} = a(\sqrt{\sin2\theta}\cos\theta + \frac{1}{2} \times 2\cos2\theta(\sin2\theta)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sin\theta)\\
=a\left(\cos\theta\sqrt{\sin2\theta} + \frac{\cos2\theta\sin\theta}{\sqrt{\sin2\theta}}\right)\\
\frac{dy}{d\theta} = 0 \Rightarrow \cos\theta = -\frac{\cos2\theta\sin\theta}{\sqrt{\sin2\theta}}\\
\Rightarrow \cos\theta\sin2\theta + \cos2\theta\sin\theta = 0\\
\Rightarrow \sin3\theta = 0\\
\Rightarrow \theta = 0, \pm\frac{\pi}{3}
$$
From the graph, $\theta \neq 0$, so the tangent parallel to the initial line (in the first quadrant) is where $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

The tangent is therefore $y=a\sqrt{\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}}\sin\frac{\pi}{3}$, and by symmetry the tangent perpendicular to the initial line in the first quadrant is $x=a\sqrt{\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}}\sin\frac{\pi}{3}$. Therefore the area is
$$\left(2a\sqrt{\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}}\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^2\\
= 4a^2\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}\sin^2\frac{\pi}{3}\\
=4a^2 \times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \times \frac{3}{4}\\
= \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}a^2$$